# @ViewChild returns undefined while using Angular Forms

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms, vmware-clarity

Below form(using Clarity Forms) is a part of a dialog:

```
<form clrForm
     clrLayout="horizontal"
     [formGroup]="editRecipientForm">
   <clr-input-container>
       <label>First Name</label>
       <input clrInput
              type="text"
              formControlName="firstName" />
       <clr-control-error>Field cannot be empty</clr-control-error>
   </clr-input-container>
   <clr-input-container>
       <label>Last Name</label>
       <input clrInput
              type="text"
              formControlName="lastName" />
       <clr-control-error>Field cannot be empty</clr-control-error>
   </clr-input-container>
</form>
```

which opens with the help of the following function:

```
onEditRecRow() {
    this.editRecipientForm = new FormGroup({
      ID: new FormControl({value: this.recSelectedList[0].ID, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
      firstName: new FormControl(this.recSelectedList[0].firstName, Validators.required),
      lastName: new FormControl(this.recSelectedList[0].lastName, Validators.required),
      emailID: new FormControl(this.recSelectedList[0].emailID, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$")])
    });

    this.editRecipientDialog = true
  }
```

Clarity helps me to prompt error messages if any Form Control is invalid.

I also wanted all Form Controls to be checked again once I save all my changes made in dialog, which I am doing in the following way:

```
  @ViewChild('ClrForm', {static: true}) clrForm;
  .
  .
  .
  onUpdateRecipient() {
    if (this.editRecipientForm.invalid) {
      this.clrForm.markAsTouched();
      console.log('Error There');
    } else {
      console.log('Recipient Updated');
    }    
  }
```

But `@ViewChild` is returning `clrForm` as undefined.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the updated answer, I missed your comment

Comment: Thanks @ShashankVivek . Can you please help me in one more error which I am getting. Please check my latest comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
@ViewChild(ClrForm, {static: true}) clrForm;
```

remove `'` (single quotes) from the statement of `@ViewChild`

#### Update (Thanks to @hippeelee)

`import {ClrForm} from '@clr/angular';`

Comment: After removing those quotes, Angular can't find ClrForm.

Comment: @Mr.A : did u try importing it ?

Comment: Can you let me know what I need to import. Thanks.

Comment: In the class with forms ViewChild you need to add ```import {ClrForm} from '@clr/angular';```

Comment: Thanks @hippeelee . I am able to import `ClrForm` properly but then next error which I get is  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'markAsTouched' of undefined` which I think is coming as clrForm is going undefined. Can you please help me in that. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.A : try `console.log(this.clrForm)` , it should say `undefined`. Can you check the initialization part of it. Please provide the exact code after implementing the suggested approach once more.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you're not referencing clrForm properly on your template?

Try `<form #ClrForm clrLayout="horizontal" [formGroup]="editRecipientForm"> <clr-input-container>`

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: According to Clarity's documentation, we can write it in that way. https://clarity.design/documentation/forms

Comment: @Mr.A can you post a stackblitz that reproduces the issue so we can see working code?  Starters for different clarity versions are here: https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team